# vnc viewer copy paste within the viewer not functional

Tags: vnc

Copy paste within a vnc viewer is not working. I tried looking up online, but most of the solutions are for copy/pasting between host and client and suggest:

```
vncconfig &
```

I tried this and it does NOT work. And my problem is about the copy/paste functionality in the vnc session itself.
Any help would be great. thanks!

Comment: Is this with only a specific target device, or ANY target device? Does the device you've VNC'd into actually support Copy/Paste?

Comment: yes, it used to copy paste before. but it stopped doing that recently. probably because I accidentally did something to the config.